# Avoiding copying Armadillo matrix when returning as part of S4 object

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a Rcpp function that takes an S4 raster object, inserts some data into a slot, and returns a new version of that object. Here is a minimal reprex:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::S4 new_raster(Rcpp::S4 raster, int n_elem) {
  Rcpp::S4 r_data(raster.slot("data"));
  r_data.slot("values") = Rcpp::NumericVector(n_elem);        

  // Need help with...
  // creating armadillo vector from `r_data.slot("values")` here
  // arma::vec new_data = ... ?

  return raster;
}

/*** R
library("raster")
r <- raster(res = 0.1)
n <- ncell(r)
r1 <- new_raster(r, n)
head(r1@data@values)
*/
```

As the data returned can be very large, I want to avoid creating more than one copy of the vector.  How can I create the Armadillo vector in the `raster@data@values` slot without copying?

Comment: Use the [advanced ctor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat) which we use too.  There is one for vectors too but it doesn't seem to have link I can use...

Comment: That's the direction I'm going, but I haven't figured out how to create the right-sized NumericVector in the sub-slot, and also get the `.begin()` to use as the memory pointer in the advanced constructor. @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, you want [advanced ctor vectors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) (e.g. `#adv_constructors_col` instead of `#adv_constructors_mat`).

Comment: That is, I can set `r_data.slot("values")  = Rcpp::NumericVector(n_elem);`, but how do I get a pointer to the start of that vector?

Comment: Define at the top of the file: `Rcpp::NumericVector A = Rcpp::NumericVector(n_elem);`, then reference it with `A.begin()`. See answer in a sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I wasn't understanding the question correctly. The objective was to *extract* information from an S4 object and share that memory with an Armadillo object. I'm leaving the first piece of this answer in place as it still has merit since it highlights how to reuse an Armadillo object memory and reassign to a `NumericVector`. Though, the second part is probably more relevant given the clarity that the question now has after Noam's response.

---

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the objective is to reuse the memory location that has been assigned to the initial Armadillo vector (e.g. the zero fill). A subgoal per the comments is to move it into a `NumericVector` at a later time.

So, here we go:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]    

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector vec_mem_ex(int n_elem) {

  // Make the initial vector
  arma::vec X(n_elem, arma::fill::zeros);

  // Create a new vector
  arma::vec Y(X.begin(), X.n_elem, false, true);
  // `copy_aux_mem` is set to false, the vector will instead directly
  // use the auxiliary memory (ie. no copying). 
  // This is dangerous in certain circumstances!

  // `strict` is set to true, the vector will be bound to the
  // auxiliary memory for its lifetime; the number of elements 
  // in the vector can't be changed

  // Show memory is shared by modifying value
  Y.fill(42.0);

  // Convert X to a NumericVector
  Rcpp::NumericVector Z = Rcpp::NumericVector(X.begin(), X.end());

  return Z;
}

/***R
(a = vec_mem_ex(5))
*/
```

This gives:

```
> (a = vec_mem_ex(5))
[1] 42 42 42 42 42
```

---

### Edit

To capture the `S4`-ness of the question and given the update via @noam-ross' answer, please consider the following:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::S4 new_raster(Rcpp::S4 raster, int n_elem) {

  // Embed S4 object for nesting
  Rcpp::S4 r_data(raster.slot("data"));

  // Create obj@data@values
  // Initializes values with a vector of 0's.
  r_data.slot("values") = Rcpp::NumericVector(n_elem);


  // --- The new part...

  // We do _not_ have access to the vector that was stored in r_data.slot("values")

  // Convert from SEXP to NumericVector
  Rcpp::NumericVector temp = Rcpp::NumericVector(r_data.slot("values"));

  // Use the advanced vector ctor of Armadillo to capture the memory location
  arma::vec new_data(
      temp.begin(), // Uses the iterator interface to access the double* requirement
      n_elem,       // Set the size of the vector
      false,        // Avoid copying by disabling `copy_aux_mem`
      true          // Bind memory by enabling `strict`
  );

  // Show memory is shared by modifying value
  new_data.fill(42.0);

  // --- End new

  return raster;
}

/*** R
library("raster")
r <- raster(res = 0.1)
n <- ncell(r)
r1 <- new_raster(r, n)
head(r1@data@values)
*/
```

Comment: That's all true but misses the S4-ness of the question, no?

Comment: Is there an advantage to creating the temporary NumericVector as opposed to the `as()` wrapping in my answer or does it all come out in the wash in the compiler?

Comment: @NoamRoss comes out to be a wash in the end. You can avoid the `temp` allocation by just replacing `temp` in the `arma::vec` ctor with `Rcpp::NumericVector(r_data.slot("values")).begin()`. Writing it in this way allows for the `NumericVector` object -- and subsequent pointer access --  to persist a bit longer in scope than just until the `arma::vec` is created and provides a means to emphasize each step of the process. Note: The cost of a `NumericVector` object from an `SEXP` is very low since it is just a pointer allocation.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by assigning an empty but right-sized NumericVector to the slot, then calling `as()` on it to find the memory pointer to use the advanced Armadillo constructor, as @DirkEddelbuettel and @coatless suggested.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::S4 new_raster(Rcpp::S4 raster, int n_elem) {
  Rcpp::S4 r_data(raster.slot("data"));
  r_data.slot("values") = Rcpp::NumericVector(n_elem);
  arma::vec new_data(
      Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(r_data.slot("values")).begin(),
      n_elem, false, true
  );
    new_data.randn();
    return raster;
}

/*** R
library("raster")
r <- raster(res = 0.1)
n <- ncell(r)
r1 <- new_raster(r, n)
head(r1@data@values)
*/
```

Result:

```
#>[1] -0.26417159 -0.89250080  2.02276338  2.01164847  0.45227281 -0.09313601
```